# Integration involving the complete elliptic integral of the first kind K(k)?

Tags: integration

Is there any reference showing how to do definite integrals involving the complete elliptic integral of the first kind K(k)? 
Something like

1. $\int_0^1 K(k) dk $
2. $\int_0^1 k^nK(k) dk$
3. $\int_0^1 \frac{K(k)}{1+k} dk $

etc...Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is Chapter 6.1 of Gradshteyn, I.S. & Ryzhik, I.M. (2007) "Table of Integrals, Series and Products", 7th edn., Amsterdam: Academic Press.

Comment: Anyway... it's good you (seem to have) specified that you were using the modulus $k$ instead of the parameter $m=k^2$ as the argument for your elliptic integrals.

Comment: The first and second one can be handled by the techniques in this paper: http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1090&context=compsci ; the last one does not seem to have a nice closed form.

Comment: J. Mangaldan, all of these integrals are available in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik. In particular, the last one is given by eq. (6.144): $$ \int_0^1\frac{K(k)}{1+k}dk=\frac{\pi^2}{8}. $$

Comment: Hmm, too bad I didn't have my copy of G&R nearby to check the third one, but the first and second one are easily handled as integrals of hypergeometric functions. Thanks for the pointer Aleksey!

Answer (score 4):

**Question bumped to the home page by Community ...**
No answer yet, I guess.  (Dan has not been here for over 6 years, so I doubt he will ever choose an answer.)

Gradshteyn & Ryzhik

6.141.1:
$$
\int_0^1 \mathbf{K}(k)\;dk = 2G
$$
where $G$ is Catalan's constant.

6.144:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\mathbf{K}(k)}{1+k}\;dk = \frac{\pi^2}{8}
$$

6.146 is a reduction formula, reducing the exponent by $2$:
$$
n^2 \int_0^1 k^n \mathbf{K}(k)\;dk
 = (n-1)^2\int_0^1 k^{n-2} \mathbf{K}(k)\;dk + 1
$$

I don't see the odd powers of $k$ directly.  Maybe you can get them using

6.142.1:
$$
\int_0^1 \left(\mathbf{K}(k) - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\;\frac{dk}{k} = \pi\log 2 - 2 G,
$$
6.142.2:
$$
\int_0^1 \left(\mathbf{K}(k) - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\;\frac{dk}{k^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} - 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

A. Dieckmann compiled a big table of indefinite and definite integrals envolving non-elementary functions. See the following links:

http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/IntegralsIndefinite/IndefInt.html

and

http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/IntegralsDefinite/DefInt.html